# Desplazamiento no deseado de imagen

Tags: html, jquery, css, typescript

Tengo una imagen identificada por jquery  $("#DetalleImagen") la cual estoy incrustando en un visualizador para que el usuario pueda realizar eventos como zoom in, zoom out, desplazar imagen en dirección del mouse y rotar.
Tengo problemas con la ultima parte.
la rotación la realiza, insertando clase `transform: rotate(270deg);` y variando el angulo deseado conforme a los eventos.
El problema es, cuando tengo grados de 270 y 90 (horizontales) al presionar la imagen y desplazarla por el visualizador. se desplaza de modo descontrolado hacia la parte inferior izquierda cada que muevo.

```
this.imgDetalle.mousedown((e) => {
        this.bandera = true;
        this.X = e.pageX;
        this.Y = e.pageY;
        return false;
    })
    .mousemove((e) => {
        if (this.bandera) {
            let deltaX: number = e.pageX - this.X;
            let deltaY: number = e.pageY - this.Y;
            if (deltaX === 0 && deltaY === 0) {
                return false;
            }

            this.imgDetalle.css({
                left: (this.imgDetalle.position().left + deltaX) + "px",
                top: (this.imgDetalle.position().top + deltaY) + "px"
            });

            this.X = e.pageX;
            this.Y = e.pageY;

            return false;
        }
    })
    .mouseup((e) => {
        this.bandera = false;
        return false;
        }).bind("mousewheel", (e: any) => {
            if (e.originalEvent.wheelDelta / 120 > 0) {
                this.EventoZoom(50);
            } else {
                this.EventoZoom(-50);
            }
        }).mouseout((e) => {
            this.bandera = false;
            return false;
        });
```

Las clases que uso de igual forma las adjunto, las agrego con cada evento de rotación

```
.imgRotada {
transform: rotate(0);
}

.imgRotada_90 {
    transform: rotate(90deg);
}

.imgRotada_180 {
    transform: rotate(180deg);
}

.imgRotada_270 {
    transform: rotate(270deg);
}
```

la bandera la ocupo para identificar cuando realmente el mouse esta presionado o no, pero aun no puedo resolver el desplazamiento deseado.

Gracias por la ayuda

Comment: tal vez tengas que recalcular el [transform-origin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-origin) debido al zoom/move

Comment: el calcular `transform-origin` solo aplicaría para el inicio, ya que al ocupar un transform simple, esta determinando de forma natural el origin al centro. el problema aqui es, que cuando desplazo una imagen con el transform en posición horizontal, me realiza un desplazamiento erroeno, veré de adjuntar un JSFiddle para mas fácil.